# Finding The Last Row With Text using a Do Loop

Tags: vba

Please Excuse My Inexperience,

I'm to write a function that returns the last row that returns a non empty string in collumn 1 using a do loop.

Comment: Could you give us a code example?

Comment: Do you **have** to use a do loop?

Comment: If this is homework you should get a "A" for saying that this task is completely unsuited to a Do loop. :) You could solve this with a standard Excel function, or with VBA you would either use Find or a search for the first unused cell from the bottom with xlUp. You would _never_ use a Do Loop.

Comment: In case you're wondering why, the problem with a do loop construct is that the condition to exit may never be true. If there are no empty rows in the column, when VBA reaches the last row and attempts to select the following cell, you get an error because you're exceeding the bounds of the sheet. Also, you have to read the value of each cell to test!!! The other bigger construct mistake is a do loop within a do loop:)

Comment: Using nested loops is not a construct mistake at all, I really don't know why you say this.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no empty rows, you could simply go with something like this :

```
Public Sub MySub()

    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set wsTarget = ActiveSheet

    Dim n As Integer
    n = 1

    Do While (wsTarget.Cells(n +1, 1).Value <> "")
        n = n + 1
    Loop

    n = n - 1

    'n now contains the line number of the last non-empty row.

End Sub
```

**Edit** : For this example, I suppose you're looking into the first column, and that the data starts on line 2. If there is no rows with data, n will be worth 1.

Comment: I edited your `wsTarget` line to look at a worksheet not workbook. As an aside vbNullstring and "" will both accept that a cell with `'` is empty. `IsEmpty` will correctly see that such a cell is non-blank

Comment: He needs a FUNCTION that returns a value, not a sub!

Comment: Yes, but he also needs to create a new type of object since a 'collumn' doesn't exist. My point being that this solution gives the key elements of how to do this with a loop, not a full solution. In an actual macro, you usually don't hardcode things like the column number, first row, etc.